# Проблема с кодировкой icq-бота

Tags: python, кодировка, бот

Здравствуйте, есть icq бот на Python, если ему отправлять сообщение на английском, то все в порядке, но вот с русскими не могу разобраться, вот сообщение, которое отправляю

> "Привет бот!"

вот, что приходит

> [('x04x1fx04@x048x042x045x04Bx00 x041x04>x04Bx00!', 'unicode')]

пробовал разные кодировки, ничего не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Можно задействовать стандартную библиотечку Python [chardet](http://wiki.python.su/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B/Python/Chardet), которая автоматически определяет кодировки сообщений.